# Why am I getting rendering issues with VS Code 1.82-1.84?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code 1.82 to 1.84 is having issues rendering the window. Sometimes the window (except for the native title bar and menu bar) is just empty, or with some shaded rectangles like parts of the sidebar or panel were partially rendered, or some parts render with a bunch of coloured artifacts. Trying to open the developer tools just shows a weird looking panel with a bunch of rendering artifacts.

When I run VS Code like `code --verbose`, I see `ERROR:shared_context_state.cc(81)] Skia shader compilation error` in the logs.

Comment: What operating system do you encounter this on? Could it be OS-specific?

Comment: @TylerH from reading bug tickets (see [#190437 and linked duplicates](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190437)) of other users' reports, mostly (all?) Linux.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TL;DR update to VS Code 1.85 once it gets released.

This is [a known issue introduced by VS Code 1.82](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_82#_update-highlights-for-chromium). VS Code 1.82 upgraded its Electron version to Electron 25, which uses Chromium `114.0.5735.289`.

Quoting from the release notes:

> Certain [Mesa](https://mesa3d.org/) version updates cause broken shader compilation leading to artifacts in application UI. The issue is tracked in [issue #190437](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190437), which also contains the link to the Chromium bug report. You can identify this issue by running with `--verbose` and looking for the following line `ERROR:shared_context_state.cc(81)] Skia shader compilation error` in the logs.
>
> **If you are affected by this issue, the current workaround is to delete the GPU cache located at ~/.config/Code/GPUCache**.

The referenced Chromium issue ticket is [Issue 1442633: Skia shader compilation error [ERROR:shared_context_state.cc]](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1442633). It has purportedly been fixed in [commit `3290d6a`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/3290d6aee7a53a6b1a811c8b50ff0a3bf84fb6a6). There's currently discussion about backporting the fix into Electron releases. <s>It'll take time for the fix to get into Electron, and then from there into VS Code.</s> The Electron backporting work has now been done by Deepak in [fix: broken shader cache due to compilation error #40450](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/40450), and the Electron bump in VS Code is done by pull request [chore: update electron@25.9.4 #198142](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/198142), which is scheduled for the November 2023 release (1.85).

Note: Very interestingly, [this redditor says that](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/16gxuf4/comment/k0gwvap/) they don't get such issues on Codium 1.82.1, which is weird because it uses the exact same version of Chromium.

It seems to happen every time you do/get a mesa update.