# Graphic issue . Vsc and NVIDIA

Tags: visual-studio-code, graphics, nvidia

It seems that the problem is coming from the Nvidia graphics card and the driver

[the problem ....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiMUr.png)

I have Rog ASUS

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:25a0] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:1638] (rev c5) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting rendering issues with VS Code 1.82?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77100725/why-am-i-getting-rendering-issues-with-vs-code-1-82) I think this is more likely due to the timing, with 1.82 being the current latest stable version of VS Code

Comment: if it's not the above, then take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/72962855/11107541 and the linked questions in the sidebar.