# Why is my Settings UI mostly blank in VS Code 1.83?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I've noticed that if I'm disconnected from the internet using Visual Studio Code, when I open the settings (with the shortcut or clicking the gear in the lower lefthand corner of the screen) or try to edit Extensions settings for some reason I only see the search settings grey bar and the rest of the screen is blank.

Should I not be able to see and change the Extension settings or VS Code settings, regardless if I'm offline or online?   I had not noticed that this was an issue in earlier verisions of VS Code.

Version: 1.83.1 (user setup)
Commit: f1b07bd25dfad64b0167beb15359ae573aecd2cc
Date: 2023-10-10T23:48:05.904Z
Electron: 25.8.4
ElectronBuildId: 24154031
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

Telemetry I think is set to all and the Output panel's various channels are empty showing no errors or no messages.

I did read though [Why am I getting rendering issues with VS Code 1.82 / 1.83?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77100725/11107541) and tried the suggested solution and still getting the blank settings screen.   I think during the initial run of VS Code I saw the settings but after that first run I just see what is pictured above when I open the settings window.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/196927 is where I've opened a new issue ticket

Answer (score 0):

Ah. I failed to find the issue ticket earlier because it's already been fixed (I was looking for open issues). See [Blank settings editor when having network issues #195722](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/195722), which is fixed in VS Code 1.84, which will release soon. If you can't wait, install VS Code Insiders. You can see the network issues in the devtools (Use `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)).