# crash color, texture vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, crash, ide

[image]

The problem is not static. When running the application, everything is fine for a while. When you start working, switch between windows, files in the editor itself, desktops. Colors change randomly, the text may partially disappear. It seems to me that the text is a little blurry.
It happens on a working laptop, which is old, but I don't think it's a problem. There are no problems with other applications, videos. There are no problems on my own laptop. The settings are synchronized, so I don't think this is the problem either. Only the browser, several pages are running in parallel. That is, there is no interference.

Why is this happening and how can I make it stop happening?

Nothing from the list helped:

- changed the font size
- full screen and in a window
- deleted and downloaded

Comment: 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) Does this happen for you in other Electron apps such as Discord, Slack, or MS Teams? Does it happen for you in any non-Electron, but Chromium-based apps such as MS Edge?

Comment: 3) it's not clear to me what in your screenshot is wrong. Can you add a screenshot of how it's supposed to look like, and circle those parts? 4) Does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77100725/11107541 or this?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72962855/11107541

Answer (score 0):

All system drivers had to be checked and updated.