# White flickery pixels appearing on screen. (Brave, VScode)

Tags: visual-studio-code, brave

First of all, I'm not really sure where to ask these type o questions, and I've been looking around for a fix for this for many hours and I did not find anything. I am gettings some shaky-flickery white pixels in apps like VSCode or Brave, which makes the coding experience really disgusting, I will add some screenshots to the question so you can see an example. I have tried uninstalling the apps where I have this problem and I have updated my graphics card drivers. I don't really know what could be the issue here, I know it is not code related, but since it is mainly happening in apps like VScode or Brave which I use to code, I thought it would not be a really bad idea to post it here. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Screenshots of what is happening:

[image]

[image]

This same thing is happening in VSCode.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/q/72962855/11107541 ? or maybe not. I've been getting rendering issues on chromium-based apps on Ubuntu Xorg for the past month that look a little similar. It seems to happen on sticky elements in particular.

Comment: or maybe this is actually a case of the chromium/mesa issue behind https://stackoverflow.com/q/77100725/11107541

Answer (score 0):

As explained on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72962855/why-does-vs-code-give-a-chip-like-distorted-display-when-i-hover-over-it-with), the problem is related to **hardware acceleration**. Follow this easy steps and it will fix the problem instantly:

- Open the command palette: `⇧+⌘+P` on Mac, `⇧+CTRL+P` on Windows/Linux.
- Search for `Preferences: Configure Runtime Arguments` and click on it.
- This will open `argv.json` file. Add `"disable-hardware-acceleration": true` to the JSON.
- Restart VS Code. The problem should be now fixed.

**NOTE: Use this settings ONLY IF you're experiencing issues.**

Credit goes to @GinoMempin, and to @starball for posting the solution question.

Comment: don't answer duplicate questions. close them. if you have a better answer, answer the duplicate-target.