how to fix VS Code black screen issue
I have successfully installed VS Code (VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.89.1). When I try to open it, I am getting black screen. I have verified the system requirements. Everything seems fine, how can I resolve this issue?
System requirements:

Processor- intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2330M CPU @ 2.20GHz   2.20 GHz
Ram - 4GB
OS- Windows 10

I tried these methods:

Method 1: Open Command Prompt then type code --disable-gpu.

Method 2: While opening VS Code click the "view menu- Command Palette..." (Or) Press In Keyboard "Ctrl+Shift+P" then type "configuration runtime argument" and click file will open, in that file type or uncomment disable-hardware-acceleration": true.

Method 3: Right click on the vs code icon and then click the properties.   In the properites the shortcut menu targer path add this line in last --disable-gpu, e.g. "C:\Users\Karthikeyan J J\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --disable-gpu.



hm. I wonder if regression of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77100725/11107541 ? have you tried the answer there?
